# What does 'unsupported initialize for address space' error mean?

Tags: opencl

I often get this error when trying to access pointers' passed by parameters in OpenCL. It doesn't happen in all drivers, mostly it appears in Mesa's implementation of OpenCL 1.1.

What does this error mean? I couldn't find anything specific even in OpenCL documentation. Also, is there a way to debug what is exactly throwing this error?

Comment: Post the result of `clinfo >> result.txt` here.

Comment: This is my clinfo output: https://gist.github.com/aegroto/d4a9e8d4c6aca7a5d24efb1c5543ef3f

Comment: Have you installed the proper AMD drivers? If you haven't then you need to.

Comment: This error happens when there's a conflict between multiple drivers or lack of proper drivers.